# « Per se » en français

Tags: usage, latin, science

> Kinematics is the study of motion per se, regardless of the forces causing it.

Peut-on rendre en français la phrase ci-dessus comme ci-dessous ?

> La cinématique est l'étude du mouvement per se, indépendamment des forces qui le provoquent.

La locution adverbiale du latin *per se* est connue en français ? Est-ce mieux d'utiliser *en soi* à sa place, soit :

> La cinématique est l'étude du mouvement en soi, indépendamment des forces qui le provoquent.

?

[La phrase originale est tirée du livre : "Continuum Mechanics", P. Chadwick, 1999 (Dover Publications).]

Comment: On peut très bien ne pas traduire *per se* qui est un peu redondant et écrire: *La cinématique est l'étude du mouvement indépendamment des forces qui le provoquent.* C'est d'ailleurs à peu de choses près ce que l'on trouve dans Wikipedia.

Comment: @jlliagre : non! le *per se* ou *en soi* apporte au-delà de seulement indépendamment des forces qui le provoquent. Il signifie le mouvement **en tant que mouvement**.

Comment: @aCOSωt+ϕ Oui. Je n'ai pas écrit que la précision n'apportait rien, seulement qu'elle était **un peu** redondante.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dans les définitions de la cinématique, les sources accessibles sur Internet n'ajoutent souvent pas de précision supplémentaire autre que l'abstraction des forces qui causent le mouvement.

On trouvera par exemple :

> - Mot qu'on a proposé pour remplacer le mot mécanique en tant qu'exprimant la science abstraite des mouvements. ([Littré](https://www.littre.org/definition/cin%C3%A9matique))
> - Partie de la mécanique qui étudie les mouvements en fonction du temps, sans se préoccuper de leurs causes. (Larousse)
> - Étude du mouvement des corps, abstraction faite des causes qui le provoquent. ([TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/cin%C3%A9matique))
> - Partie de la mécanique ayant pour but de donner une description géométrique du mouvement d'un point ou d'un système physique. Contrairement à la dynamique, la cinématique ne traite ni des masses ni des forces.  ([Académie](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie9/cin%C3%A9matique))
> - La cinématique est la théorie qui, à l'intérieur de la mécanique, a pour objet la description des mouvements des systèmes matériels. ([Encyclopædia Universalis](https://www.universalis.fr/encyclopedie/cinematique/))
> - En physique, la cinématique (du grec kinêma, le mouvement) est l'étude des mouvements indépendamment des causes qui les produisent, ou, plus exactement, l'étude de tous les mouvements possibles. ([Wikipedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cin%C3%A9matique))
> - La cinématique est aussi appelée la spécialité de la physique, qui est centrée sur l’analyse du mouvement, sans tenir compte des caractéristiques des forces qui le génèrent. ([definition-simple.com](https://definition-simple.com/cinematique/))

Si l'on souhaite néanmoins rendre le sens de *per se*, en plus d'*étude du mouvement **en soi***, qui introduit un peu de redondance car **en soi** signifie ici *abstraction faite de tout autre chose* (cf. [Gabriel Wyler](http://gabrielwyler.com/page202.html)), on peut aussi proposer :

> La cinématique est l'étude du mouvement **en tant que tel**, indépendamment des forces qui le provoquent.

Comment: Cela veut-il dire qu'on peut dire que la cinématique n'est _pas_ l'étude de la nature du mouvement ? Merci !

Answer (score 5):

*per se* est une locution adverbiale tout à fait légitime en français mais sortie d'usage depuis un certain temps.

Dans les exemples que tu donnes, on utilisera sans aucun doute *en soi*.
*Le mouvement en soi* ; et tout le monde comprendra qu'il s'agit du mouvement, en tant que mouvement, c'est à dire pas du mouvement de telle ou telle chose ni du mouvement provoqué par telle ou telle autre. Mais bien du mouvement en général.

Nota : Cet *en soi* se comprendra ainsi très bien en sciences physiques.
Il a en revanche, et ce depuis au moins Kant, très mauvaise presse en philosophie et sciences humaines. L'utiliser dans ces contextes revient à affirmer que l'on ne sait pas de quoi on parle ou, si on sait, s'exposer à un *flagrant délit d'idéalisme*. ;)